# Python3 VLC is only playing sound the first time

Tags: python-3.x, python-vlc

I have a function, and whenever it is called one of the lines has it run `sound.play()`, which works fine the first time. as soon as i hit the loop the second time, it doesn't do anything. just passes by the sound. but everything else works.

```py
def s_js(): 
    global plane 
    global has_food 
    global has_sound 
    global s_disable 
    global x 
    plane -= 10 
    has_food = False 
    has_sound = False 
    scary.play() 
    while x != 20: 
        chosenimg = pygame.image.load(s.crowjs[x]) 
        newimg = pygame.transform.scale(chosenimg, (1400, 750)) 
        screen.blit(newimg, (0, 0)) 
        pygame.display.flip() 
        time.sleep(.03) 
        x += 1 
        s.loc = 4 
        s_disable = False
```

Comment: Question needs some code:
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ```def s_js():

    global plane

    global has_food

    global has_sound

    global s_disable

    global x

    
    plane -= 10

    has_food = False

    has_sound = False

    
    scary.play()

    while x != 20:
        chosenimg = pygame.image.load(s.crowjs[x])
        newimg = pygame.transform.scale(chosenimg, (1400, 750))
        screen.blit(newimg, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(.03)
        x += 1
    s.loc = 4

    s_disable = False

Comment: please see modified question (with code) and update...